# How do I uniquely identify a database in MySql?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I'm in an environment where in order to connect to the SQL database, I first need to create a tunnel that redirects the local port to a remote machine.
I connect to a different db server, depending on the port number in the tunnel.

In other words: I always connect to MySql with the same parameters to localhost. The tunnel created beforehand is what defines the server I actually connect to.

There are several MySql servers, all with the same schema (for testing purposes) and I want to know which actual database I'm connected to (my script doesn't have access to the tunnel parameters to know).

When we create a new db, is there a GUID or something that gets attributed to it? Perhaps something I can retrieve with a query to `information_schema`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the schema name is the identifier.

You may want to set `server_id` uniquely on each of your MySQL instances. This is an integer in the range 1 through 2<sup>32</sup>-1 that you configure in your MySQL instance's `my.cnf` file.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-options.html#option_mysqld_server-id

Usually `server_id` is used to tag changes in the binary log, so replica sets don't replay changes they've already seen.

But you can read the `server_id` in any SQL query:

```
SELECT @@server_id;
```

And based on its value, you will know which MySQL instance you're on, assuming you have set every instance's `server_id` according to some design so you'll know.

Comment: Awesome, exactly what I needed!